# EF and SQL Server CE with NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, nuget, nuget-package

While poking around NuGet I noticed a couple of packages that I have already installed, EF and SQL Server CE. This raised a couple of questions that I have not been able to find any information on.

1. On EF package what does this add that isn't already there in VS or does it just do all the reference work for you?
2. On SQL Server CE package, what does this add that installing it doesn't? Or is this just a better way to install it.

It certainly takes a lot to get an environment setup and I like NuGet for other packages, but I do not want to break anything unless it would ultimately benefit me in the long run. Any comments, answers, or anecdotes would be great.

Answer (score 3):

NuGet is definately the way forward for all binary references and even project tooling such as NUnit etc.

I'd recommend bringing in the combined EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact package.  This will add the latest binaries for each and also hook up the correct provider factory config and add a WebActivator in the  App_Start folder for Connection Factory initialisation.  The WebActivator works in both ASP.NET and Web Forms but will invariably cause a compile error in a none Web based project but this is no big deal.

Comment: Thats the kind of info I was looking for.  But, that last part kind of scared me...  I'm working with a WPF app.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing it adds is that those assemblies are now bin deployed and part of your solution. For example, if you commit the packages folder as part of your project, and someone checks it out but doesn't have EF or SQLCE installed, the project will still compile and work.  They don't need to go hunting for the MSI installers.

Secondly, if you deploy to a server that doesn't have these DLLs in the GAC (most don't), well you'll still be ok because they will be set to "Copy Local to True".