# Configuring a project for Entity Framework 4.3, SQL Server Compact 4, and WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

This [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361121/ef-and-sqlce-with-nuget) mentions the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact NuGet package, but it seems to suggest that it's for web-based projects.  So how should I configure a WPF project to use EF and SQLCE?

Comment: Perhaps another way of framing this question: If I select "Generate Database from Model" when right clicking on an .edmx file, I never see the option to use Compact 4.0 as the data source in a non-web based project (Compact 3.5 is there, but not Compact 4.0). Why?

Comment: @JayBorseth References -> Add reference -> System.Data.SqlServerCe ver.4.0 on your project

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there is an unfortunate mis-conception there. That even I had.

The [SqlCe Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.sqlservercompact) can be used for any project. **However** when you try to use it from any project **other than web projects** you get:

> The type or namespace name 'WebActivator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Quick fixes:

- When you get the error, double clicking it opens `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.cs`. Comment out all the code in there. (The file resides in the `/App_Start` and Deleting the file causes an error)

OR

- Change your assembly/project to target the Full .NET install **instead** of client profile.

The reason is that they use the [WebActivator](http://nuget.org/packages/WebActivator) package to execute some startup code. This package **is installed** but needs `System.Web` which is not part of `Client Profile`.

The above is the ***tl:dr*** version of what I learned from here:
http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/1025/one-click-install-nuget-package-and-console-applications

Comment: I'm interested in a better fix. This is a WPF app so System.Web should not be involved.

Comment: After following steps from @gideon , you may try following to escape the System.Web dependency. Remove the reference to 'WebActivator', and commenting all the code inside EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.cs and shift the code : Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"); into the event : void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e){...} under App.xaml.cs ?

Comment: Would it be easier to not use EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact  but the individual packages instead?

Comment: @HappyNomad I think just commenting out the code and removing the reference to WebActivator is a pretty simple solution, you still are targeting client profile.